# How to move vector graphic in the direction it is pointing in Java

Tags: java, vector-graphics

After a long battle with `Graphics2D`, I have finally been able to draw, rotate and move a small triangle in an applet. Now what I want to do is find the angle the triangle is pointing in, then move it in that direction. Is there a method or algorithm to make it do this? I have tried this:

```
public double calcAngleMoveX(double angle)
    {
        return (double)(Math.cos(angle*Math.PI/180));
    }
public double calcAngleMoveY(double angle)
    {
        return (double)(Math.sin(angle*Math.PI/180));
    }
```

```
ship.incY(ship.calcAngleMoveY(ship.getFaceAngle()-90));
ship.incX(ship.calcAngleMoveX(ship.getFaceAngle()-90));
```

But it does really strange things. Can anyone solve this for me?

EDIT:
This is my code in `paint()`:

```
        g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        AffineTransform identity = new AffineTransform();
        g2d.drawString(Double.toString(ship.getX()),100,100);
        g2d.drawString(Double.toString(ship.getY()),100,120);
        int width = getSize().width;
        int height = getSize().height;
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2d.fillRect(0,0,width,height);
        g2d.translate(ship.getX(),ship.getY());
        g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(ship.getFaceAngle()));
        g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
        g2d.fill(shape);
```

And this is my keyPressed method:

```
int ke = e.getKeyCode();
        switch(ke)
        {
        case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
            ship.setFaceAngle(ship.getFaceAngle()-5);
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
            ship.setFaceAngle(ship.getFaceAngle()+5);
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
            ship.incX(ship.calcAngleMoveX(ship.getFaceAngle())*ship.velocity);
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
            ship.incY(ship.calcAngleMoveY(ship.getFaceAngle())*ship.velocity);
            break;
        }
        repaint();
```

These are the calculation methods:

```
public double calcAngleMoveX(double angle)
    {
        return (double)(Math.sin(angle * Math.PI / 180.0));
    }
    public double calcAngleMoveY(double angle)
    {
        return (double)(-Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180.0));
    }
```

Comment: really strange things... can you elaborate?

Comment: @greedybuddha I can't really explain it. Basically moving in a way it's not supposed to

Comment: What is 0 degrees? Up or to the right?

Comment: @greedybuddha up. So if ship is pointing at 90 degrees, it should move right etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ship movement depends on the coordinate system used in your graphics.

Since you've said 90 degrees is "right", I'm going to assume that you're using *clockwise* bearings, with 0 degrees as "up".

Rather than manipulating the angle to convert from the cartesian convention of 0 degrees being right and then rotating clockwise, it's easier to simply flip around which trigonometric function you call for each axis.

`Graphics2D`, like most other graphics systems, uses increasing X coordinates as you move right, so:

```
delta_x = Math.sin(angle * Math.PI / 180.0)
```

You should be able to trivially see that this gives `delta_x = 1.0` for 90 degrees, and `delta_x = -1.0` for 270 degrees.

In `Graphics2D` Y coordinates increase as you move *downwards* (i.e. `[0, 0]` is at top-left), so use:

```
delta_y = -Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180.0)
```

Giving `delta_y = -1.0` for 0 degrees, and `delta_y = 1.0` for 180 degrees.

If you were using a system with `[0, 0]` at bottom-left you would just remove the unary minus (`-`) from the `delta_y` formula.

Comment: Can you please show how this could be applied? Should I increase the X and Y values of my graphic by delta_x and delta_y, or is that the wrong way to do it?

Comment: @imulsion yes, those represent your `MoveX` and `MoveY` results.

Comment: Did you remove the `- 90` from the calls to `.incX` and `.incY`?  It's unnecessary with these versions of `MoveX` and `MoveY` which take the coordinate system into account and automatically treat 0 degrees as "up".

Comment: there's something else wrong in your code, then - I can assure you that these formulae are correct for mapping a clockwise bearing into a direction vector with `[0, 0]` at top left, and with 90' facing right.

Comment: @imulsion your problem appears to be that when you press `up` or `down` you're only moving in _either_ `X` or `Y`, but whichever is pressed you need to be moving in _both_ dimensions (albeit in the opposite direction for `down`).

Comment: @imulsion to show this is the case, you _should_ find with your current code that if you alternate between pressing `up` and `down` that the ship will actually travel in the direction required, with the `up` strokes making it move laterally and the `down` strokes making it move vertically.